# The Aspect of Peryite came out of nowhere and insisted on talking with my character.. forever - How do I stop him?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I experienced a gameplay-killing and savegame persistent bug, where the 'Aspect of Peryite' initiates a conversation and will initiate again after finishing or if you tabbed out of it. My last savegame was somewhere in Windhelm (not in an indoor location) when I noticed this bug.

The conversation that he insists on talking about is his Daedric quest, [The Only Cure](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure). This is the last conversation he gives you before giving you the quest reward and letting you go. Even if you 'finish' the conversation, he'll initiate another conversation a second or two later. Going to another indoor location, will not stop Peryite, as he will initiate the same conversation again.

I have already finished the quest, 'The Only Cure', months ago (both real-world time and game-time). This bug only happened in the savegame of my oldest character (Level 59) who has finished that quest. I have a Level 20+ and 30+ character — but with the same set of mods, the Aspect of Peryite doesn't haunt them.

A possible cause is due to a removed mod. I tried reinstalling all mods that might have caused this, but the bug persists (I might have forgotten what that mod was or have deleted that mod — either way, I can't 'restore' that mod). I tried removing all mods and then loading older savegames (which are in different locations other than Windhelm), but to my dismay, the Aspect of Peryite is still there, haunting me forever.

A possible fix I can think of is to use the `disable` command on the Aspect of Peryite. However, I can't target the Aspect of Peryite (he's invisible — although in the [related quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure), he is not [might be because the character *was* on hallucinogens]) and I don't know his RefID (tried UESP and TES Wiki, but it isn't there). I tried blindly shooting the `disable` command on whatever my cursor targets, but Peryite can't be hit (I mostly ended up disabling walls and stuff). I tried the `help` console command, but I can't find the right RefID.

Does anyone know any solutions or troubleshooting methods? Or can anyone tell me the Aspect of Peryite's RefID or BaseID, so I could disable him forever thru console commands? What about other console commands or mods that will fix this? (I already tried `disable` and `setstage` — to no avail.)

Screenshot of the Aspect of Peryite trying to initiate conversation in Windhelm:
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
(It's basically these two screenshots repeating over and over again.)

My list of mods (.ESP filenames from BOSS' modlist.txt): http://tinypaste.com/458eef93

Nexus Mod Manager-installed mods, with mod names screenshot (unchecked ones have not been used at the time of the loading of the game):

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Savegame file of the affected character: http://www.mediafire.com/?7cguri2za1i4z6i

I use [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=6) and [Wrye Bash (AKA Wrye Smash)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1840). I am currently using [Skyrim version 1.5.26.0.5](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.5.26.0.5) and the issue still persists.

There is no mention of this bug on [the list of bug fixes in the official patch updates](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch).

Based on the reports I found below and their dates, this happens on Skyrim versions 1.4.21.0.4 – 1.5.24.0 – 1.5.26.0.5.

This bug has been previously reported here:
http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1355973-aspect-of-peryite-dialogue-spam-loop-poss-spoilers/

> I've completed The Only Cure quest long time ago. Lately, in the wilderness, upon loading a saved game, the Aspect of Peryite dialogue appeared and started to spam me (with the dialogue that supposed to be in the end of the quest). The camera angle is limited, so I can turn from left to right, but cannot turn around. If I choose dialogue option or Tab out of conversation it opens again, usually immediately, sometimes after two or three seconds. If I try to talk to someone else, the Peryite dialogue takes over no matter how fast I am.

and here: http://www.loverslab.com/showthread.php?tid=6368 (some forum user avatars are NSFW)

> A strange bug has struck me that randomly engages dialouge with peryite out of nowhere after deactivating a random mod. installing the mod again seems to freeze the problem but so does quest advancement and receiving items.

and here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/62113942

> (*about the Aspect of Peryite*) Im in Windhelm. he talked to me and my game froze.

> No it is not just sound, the subtitle Aspect of Peryite appears.

> I was in Jorrvaskr when I saved my game. When I reload, it says 'aspect of peryite' on the screen. I can see Companions walking around , my mouse moves but nothing else works. I saved right in front of the door to skyrim, But can't open it, I can't use 'Tab", Esc doesn't work either . I have to Ctrl, Alt, Del and then quickly press the Windows key to end the game...

and here: http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1361006-aspect-of-peryite-comes-out-of-nowhere-and-insists-that-you-talk-to-him-forever-bug/page__view__findpost__p__20544773

> Got the same and horrible problem, since steam's patch 1.5.
> My main lvl45 character finished the quest a long time ago (around the lvl25) but the AoP still talk to me.

> Can't find the RefID of him, neither a way to un-complete the quest, nor something to delete the voice. If i launch a "resetquest DA13" the AoP won't talk to me anymore, but no NPC either.

> The only way i find to be able to speak with NPC et shut the mouth of AoP, is to do in console : "setstage DA13 0". Unfortunately, the screen sparkle like the beginning of the quest (under drugs effects). Can't find a way to disable (in console mode) this effect....

I tried the commands posted by this user too and also got more bugs. Bugs I notice: NPCs won't respond properly to conversation (not reply to you when you choose a certain conversation path - leaving you stuck), merchants won't open the buy/sell window, horses can't be ridden, and other interaction issues.

Other reports:

- https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/607426-coversation-with-npc-huge-issues
- [http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/563855-the-arena/page__view__findpost__p__4811044](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/563855-the-arena/page-18#entry4811044)

Comment: You've done your research.  Hopefully a bounty will help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How to fix (2013 update)

I've tried the bugged saved game file I initially posted in my question with the current latest versions of the [official patch](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch), [Unofficial Skyrim Patch (USKP)](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19/?) and [Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE)](http://skse.silverlock.org/), and the saved game is now Aspect of Peryite-free.

I've configured SKSE to use its `ClearInvalidRegistrations` console command on every saved game load, which removes invalid scripts left running by uninstalled mods. This feature was introduced in [v1.6.7 of SKSE](http://skse.silverlock.org/skse_whatsnew.txt):

> add console command `ClearInvalidRegistrations` to remove invalid
>   OnUpdate() registrations
>
> This prevents orphaned OnUpdate() events and
>   the resulting bloated/broken saves when removing certain mods. When
>   applied to an already bloated save, it will stop growing further and
>   instead shrink over time as the game processes all queued events. This
>   may take hours depending on the amount of bloat.
>
> To execute automatically after each reload, add this to `\Data\SKSE\skse.ini`:
>
> `[General]`
>   `ClearInvalidRegistrations=1`

---

According* to a developer of the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch (USKP)](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19/?), the underlying cause is because DA13 [('The Only Cure' quest)](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure) is never stopped.

A possible fix* for this:

> In the meantime, load an affected save, then type `stopquest DA13` into the console. That ought to put an end to that. Plus it’ll free up some unnecessarily leftover alias memory.
>
> BTW, don’t use the console command on a save not bothered by it. Even though it may appear benign, console commands can have negative consequences you don’t know about.

If this doesn't work or if you experience issues like: NPCs not responding properly to conversation (not reply to you when you choose a certain conversation path - leaving you stuck), merchants not opening the buy/sell window, horses that can't be ridden, and other interaction issues, then the save game is most likely corrupted. Try the SKSE `ClearInvalidRegistrations` console command fix I've posted above, instead.

To *prevent* this from happening in the PC, get the latest version of the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.darkcreations.org/forums/files/file/289-unofficial-skyrim-patch/). This has been fixed since [version 1.1](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) of the USKP:

> "The Only Cure" (DA13) was never stopped which would lead to the Aspect of Peryite randomly initiating conversation and being unable to exit.

---

<sup>* This info is from the [old USKP bug tracker page at 16bugs.com,](https://unofficialskyrimpatch.16bugs.com/projects/7078/bugs/223421) which is now not viewable. [The new USKP bug tracker report page of this bug is at afkmods.iguanadons.net](http://afkmods.iguanadons.net/index.php?app=trac&module=issues&section=issues&do=view&id=5325).</sup>

Comment: Oh wow, SKSE fixed Skyrim's save bloat? Those guys should make the next Elder Scrolls game.

Comment: @kotekzot Yeah, `ClearInvalidRegistrations` helps lower save game bloat. It also fixes slow downs and some errors caused by invalid scripts of uninstalled mods.

Answer (score 0):

Try the setstage command : SetStage

So it would be "SetStage DA13 100"  DA13 is The only Cure 100 ist the completed quest

EDIT: if that doesn't work try the "resetquest" Command "resetquest DA13"

Comment: In my question, I quoted [someone at the Bethesda forums that posted about the same bug and tried doing those console commands](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1361006-aspect-of-peryite-comes-out-of-nowhere-and-insists-that-you-talk-to-him-forever-bug/page__p__20544773#entry20544773). Like him, I tried the commands too and also got more bugs. Bugs I notice: NPCs won't respond properly to conversation (not reply to you when you choose a certain conversation path - leaving you stuck), merchants won't open the buy/sell window, horses can't be ridden, and other interaction issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try killing him.

You can type "setessential (base ID) 0" in the console to make a NPC that is immortal killable. You can look up the base ID of your specific NPC on the skyrim wiki. Then you just click on the npc and type kill.

Comment: The Aspect of Peryite is invisible and immaterial (can't be hit or targeted). I've already mentioned in the question that I can't target him with console commands: "*I can't target the Aspect of Peryite (he's invisible - although in the related quest, he is not) and I don't know his RefID (tried UESP.net, but it isn't there). I tried blindly shooting the 'disable' command on whatever my cursor targets, but Peryite can't be hit (I mostly ended up disabling walls and stuff). I tried the 'help' console command, but I can't find the right RefID.*" Also, there's no AoP BaseID at UESP or TES Wiki.

Comment: If you do find the RefID or BaseID of the Aspect of Peryite, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a bug fix for a couple of days now. I found out that if you teleport to `COC QASMOKE`, that command will bring you to the developer's testing cells. It will bring up a list of statements, chose the last one, it will then allow you to move again, but will quickly stop you and make you talk to him again. So after it lets you free, pull up the command prompt again and use `SetStage DA13 100` to complete the quest. Then teleport back to wherever, I used `COC RIVERWOOD`.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. (Although I might have did something wrong.) "*...that command will bring you to the developer's testing cells. It will bring up a list of statements, chose the last one*" Are you talking about the AoP's conversation options here? "*So after it lets you free*" If yes, does it mean I have to talk to the AoP twice when in QASMOKE?

Comment: Could you also please try [the savegame of my affected character](http://www.mediafire.com/?7cguri2za1i4z6i), and see if it works when you do the fix with that save?

Comment: Ok so I used your save file, I was able to un-bug it by selecting the first dialog. Then using the console command "resetquest da13" After using the command, wait a couple of seconds and he'll talk again and you'll be able to move correctly. If that doesn't work for you I'll upload the save file I fixed for you to Mediafile.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried `resetquest DA13`. But I got bugs. Bugs I notice: NPCs won't respond properly to conversation (not reply to you when you choose a certain conversation path - leaving you stuck), merchants won't open the buy/sell window, horses can't be ridden, and other interaction issues. See the post I quoted from the Bethesda forums in my questions and [my comment to this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60500/4797). What about the `coc qasmoke` - `setstage da13 100` method? Did it work with my save file?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I was able to fix it by reinstalling the mod "arrows stick", available on the skyrim workshop. You should try it, too!
Hope this will help!

Comment: I've never installed that mod. But yes, if you do know which mod caused the issue, I guess you could install it back and fix the issue. Based on the many reports I've seen, there are a lot of culprit mods that could cause this upon uninstallation. I'll try to compile them and see which one could have caused it in my case.